# Openssl adding a telephone number or cell number to the distinguished_name

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, openssl, x.509

In the openssl.cnf file, I see fields like countryName, stateOrProvinceName etc which are typically present in the distinguished_name. Where can I get a list of fields which can be added to the distinguished_name?

I want to add a mobile(cellular) number to the distinguished_name. How do I go about doing this?

I tried adding stuff like telephoneName, telephone_default, telephone_min, telephone_max to distinguished_name in openssl.cnf but openssl seems to ignore it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**telephoneNumber** is what you're looking for.

Add the following to openssl.cnf; I used the Ubuntu 14 system version to start with, section names may vary by your distribution:

Under policy_match and policy_anything sections (probably policy_* in whatever openssl.cnf you're using as a template):

```
telephoneNumber         = optional
```

Under req_distinguished_name section:

```
telephoneNumber                 = Telephone Number
telephoneNumber_min             = 11
telephoneNumber_max             = 40
```

Then generate a key and CSR as normal.  The interactive prompts will now include a telephone number:

```
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:US
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:Massachusetts
Locality Name (eg, city) []:Boston
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:www.example.com
Email Address []:root@example.com
Telephone Number []:617-555-1234
```

And you can verify that the telephone number makes it into the cert:

```
$ openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout | grep Subject:
Subject: C=US, ST=Massachusetts, L=Boston, O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, CN=www.example.com/emailAddress=root@example.com/telephoneNumber=617-555-1234
$
```

Some references as to how I figured this out:

[RFC 5280](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt) says that

> Standard sets of attributes have been defined in the X.500 series of
>   specifications [X.520].

A bit of Googling led me to [Naming and Structuring Guidelines for X.500 (RFC 1617)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1617.txt) which has section "4.4.7 Telecom Attributes".  There's not much info there but it does state telephoneNumber.  So I Googled for that along with openssl.cnf and found an [example openssl.cnf file incorporating telephoneNumber](https://github.com/WrathOfChris/chopstix/blob/master/cust/licence/openssl.cnf).  From there it was simple to test the necessary parameters on my own system.

Finally, knowing that telephoneNumber is a valid thing, it was possible to Google "site:openssl.org telephoneNumber" and the [source code for obj_mac.h](http://git.openssl.org/gitweb/?p=openssl.git;a=blob;f=crypto/objects/obj_mac.h;h=b5ea7cdab4f84b90280f0a3aae1478a8d715c7a7;hb=46ebd9e3bb623d3c15ef2203038956f3f7213620) has that along with facsimileTelephoneNumber, homeTelephoneNumber, mobileTelephoneNumber, and pagerTelephoneNumber.  (Personally, I think if you're just putting one number in, you should be general ("telephoneNumber") rather than pedantic ("mobileTelephoneNumber"), so that's what I've used above).